# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetchPersonnelList')

Tags: angular, angular-test

I am getting an error with my test spec:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetchPersonnelList')`

Here is my full code:

```
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
    async,
    ComponentFixture,
    fakeAsync,
    flush,
    TestBed,
    tick,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { SharedModule } from '../../../../../shared/shared.module';
import { PersonnelDataService } from '../services/personnel-data.service';
import { testHFSTaleSchema } from './hfs-table.schema';
import { ListPersonnelComponent } from './list-personnel.component';

const mockPersonnelDataService = {
    list$: of(testHFSTaleSchema.rows),
    fetchPersonnelList: function () {
        return { subscribe: () => this.list$ };
    },
    setPageSize: function () {
        return this.list$;
    },
    fetchPaginatedList: () => {},
};

@Component({
    selector: 'app-details-personnel',
    template: '',
})
export class PersonnelDetailsComponent {}

fdescribe('ListPersonnelComponent', () => {
    let component: ListPersonnelComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListPersonnelComponent>;
    let activatedRoute = { url: {} } as ActivatedRoute;
    let service: PersonnelDataService;
    let router;
    const routes = [
        {
            path: 'personnel-details',
            component: PersonnelDetailsComponent,
        },
    ];

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes),
                SharedModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
                HttpClientModule,
            ],
            declarations: [ListPersonnelComponent],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: PersonnelDataService,
                    useValue: mockPersonnelDataService,
                },
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoute },
            ],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListPersonnelComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        router = TestBed.inject(Router);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should call fetchPersonnelList on page Oninit', fakeAsync(() => {
        component.ngOnInit();
        tick(1000);
        expect(service.fetchPersonnelList).toHaveBeenCalled();//error
        flush();
    }));
});
```

### Update

As per `forestG` suggestion I update the code by injecting service. When mock service existing, still I am getting an error as :

`Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.`

When mock service added, why I am getting this error?

### Suggestion update

I have updated my code like:

```
it('should call fetchPersonnelList on page Oninit', fakeAsync(() => {
        const fetchPersonnelListSpy = spyOn(
            service,
            'fetchPersonnelList'
        ).and.returnValue(of([]));
        component.ngOnInit();
        tick(1000);
        expect(fetchPersonnelListSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
        flush();
    }));
```

it works. But what is the benefit of my mock service? How can I expect my mock data? I can put my data directly in the `retunValue` part, right?

Comment: service is not defined

Comment: @MWO - can you check my comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to directly spy on the service `spyOn(component.service, 'fetchPersonnelList')` and use `.callThrough()` which will call the mock function, if you want to prevent calling the mock function and pass some other value then use `.returnValue(of([]));`

```js
it('should call fetchPersonnelList on page Oninit', () => {
  const fetchPersonnelListSpy = spyOn(component.service, 'fetchPersonnelList').and.callThrough();
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(fetchPersonnelListSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to get a reference to your service:

```
   beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListPersonnelComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        router = TestBed.inject(Router);
        service = TestBed.inject(PersonnelDataService);  // add this
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

Comment: Even it's provided already is it required to inject? after I made change getting error as ` Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.` when i have the mock service already why i am getting this error?

Comment: try, const fetchPersonnelListSpy = spyOn(service, 'fetchPersonnelList'); expect(fetchPersonnelListSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: @Mr.Stash, can you look at my `suggestion update `  please?

Comment: @3gwebtrain you get the error because you only configure the test module, but do not initialize the service properly. Calling "inject" will in fact tells the Angular DI engine to provide an instance of the service for you. Using a spyOn goes around this, as you replace the reference with a SpyObject.  Your code (  expect(fetchPersonnelListSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();) only works on the spyObject though. So you either use that, or what I suggested.